# Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file

Tags: typescript, npm, jestjs, babeljs

I'm trying to install Jest for use with Babel and Typescript. I've followed the instructions [shown here](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started) to the letter but I'm getting:

> Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file C:...jest.config.js`

...when I run `npm run test`.

The contents of `jest.config.ts` is:

```
export default {
    //lots of commented-out stuff in here - nothing at all uncommented
}
```

Here's the exact steps I did:

- init project - `npm init -y`
- install Jest - `npm -i --save-dev jest`
- make a script (sum.js) and a test (sum.test.js) file:

sum.js:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

sum.test.js

```
const sum = require('./sum');
test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

- add `test` command to `package.json`:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "jest-learn",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1"
  }
}
```

**At this point, if I run `yarn test`, my test runs and passes just fine. The problem is when I try to introduce Babel and Typescript.** Steps continue:

- install Babel deps: `npm -i --dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env`
- create `babel.config.js`
- install Typescript: `npm -i --dev @babel/preset-typescript`
- add `@babel/preset-typescript` to `babel.config.js`:

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
};
```

Now when I run `npm run test` I get the above error. What did I do wrong?

Comment: same issue... Any fix?

Comment: I have same similar issue when I update Jest from 27.5.1 to >=28. 
Are you sure you have error about .js file, not .ts ?

`Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file C:...jest.config.js`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me [from Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/configuration):

- create and add file `jest.config.ts` to your source directory with content like:

```
    /** @type {import('jest').Config} */
        const config = {
            verbose: true,
        };
      
    module.exports = config;
```

- Then, make sure to include the file in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
    ...
    "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts", "src/jest.config.ts"]
```

- in your packages.json: Ensure also that you have installed `jest`, `ts-jest`, and `ts-node-dev` modules:

```
    ...
    },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@faker-js/faker": "^7.5.0",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
        "@types/jest": "^29.0.3",
        "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
        "jest": "^29.0.3",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
        "ts-jest": "^29.0.2",
        "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.8.3"
      }
```

and that the jest transform configuration script looks like:

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      ".(ts|tsx)": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: why do I need a jest transform config in the package.json, when I have a jest.config.ts file?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed for me by just [installing TS Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node).